# Is there an easy way to distinguish suspicious blocks?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Minecraft 1.20 version introduced two new blocks called Suspicious Sand and Suspicious Gravel, which can be brushed to discover items. Those blocks are very fragile, because you lose their loot when broken, and that happens also when they fall to the ground.

So I'm wondering: is there an easy way to distinguish normal Sand from Suspicious Sand? Or do I have to brush every sand block to find out?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> You can tell suspicious sand from the regular variety by a subtle difference in the texture. Suspicious sand has slightly darker spots on the surface, compared to regular sand which is one color. [Source](https://pcgamesn.com/minecraft/suspicious-sand)

[image]

[Source](https://sportskeeda.com/minecraft/what-suspicious-sand-minecraft)

The same goes with gravel. It is slightly darker than the normal. Basically for both gravel and sand the suspicious blocks have a "crack" in the middle of them.  It is not terribly hard to find.

Comment: In the screenshot, are the tiles in boxes both suspicious, or is one regular and one suspicious and they're both in boxes for comparison? I suspect they're both sus, but it's hard to be certain

Comment: No they're both suspicious sand :P @MooingDuck

Answer (score 37):

Use a texture pack, like the example below.

[image: example texture pack]

Comment: Well, this is indeed sus.

Comment: [xD] Yea, it was the only good example I could find... JK I picked this one on purpose lol.

Comment: Can you link the exact texture pack?

Comment: I like the lore this texture pack introduces to Minecraft. It's like the Among Us characters were from an ancient civilization within the world of Minecraft.

Comment: You know, it kind of does...

Comment: The pyramids were built by very sus aliens.